# How to deploy a functionapp from remote zip file using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell

I want to deploy a functionApp in azure using a zip file which is in another azure blob storage using powershell.
I tried like following method

```
#PowerShell
$username = "<deployment_user>"
$password = "<deployment_password>"
$filePath = "https://xxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/container/zzzz.zip"
$apiUrl = "https://<app_name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy"
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f 
$username, $password)))
$userAgent = "powershell/1.0"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -UserAgent $userAgent -Method POST -InFile $filePath - ContentType "multipart/form-data"
```

But I got the following error message like

> Invoke-RestMethod : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'https' does not exist.

How I do the deployment from a remote url file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Invoke-RestMethod` `InFile` accepts the content from a file, blob content needs to be explicitly downloaded first.

**Option 1**

```
$fileUrl = "https://xxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/container/zzzz.zip"
$token = 'sp=r&st=2019-07-06T21:41:45Z&se=2019-07-07T05:41:45Z&spr=https&sv=2018-03-28&sig=9ud%2FiJ6GBccxZfyrKsZtP69lwuralu1D0QiiESa%2FXgo%3D&sr=b'
$filePath = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($fileUrl)
Invoke-WebRequest ('{0}?{1}' -f $fileUrl, $token) -OutFile $filePath
```

> **Prerequisite**
>
> Instead of resource Url, [SAS (Shared Access Signature) URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1) needs to be provided 
>   which includes a SAS token to perform the *authenticated*
>   request

**Option 2**

Via [Azure Storage Cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/?view=azurermps-6.13.0):

```
$StorageAccountName = 'yourstorageaccount'
$StorageAccountKey = Get-AzureStorageKey -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName
$StorageContext = New-AzureStorageContext $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey.Primary
$FileName = 'zzzz.zip'
$OutputPath = 'C:\Temp'
$ContainerName  = 'yourcontainer'
Get-AzureStorageBlobContent -Blob $FilebName -Container $ContainerName -Destination $OutputPath -Context $StorageContext
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -UserAgent $userAgent -Method POST -InFile $filePath - ContentType "multipart/form-data"
```

> -InFile $filePath

param expect the path of file locally.

Check the documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-6

Use something like:

1. First, download the blob from Azure Storage.
2. Convert into byte stream.
3. Set as a part of your request (Body).

Sample Code for reference:

```
$base64Image = [convert]::ToBase64String((get-content $path -encoding byte))
```

`Invoke-WebRequest -uri $uri -Method Post -Body $base64Image -ContentType "application/base64"`